# Create MessageDigest with Guice

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to find a way to initialize MessageDigest with Guice. Currently I have this:

```
public class MyClass {

    MessageDigest md;
    
    public MyClass() {
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
....
}
```

I'm trying to see if it can written as:

```
@Inject
MessageDigest md;
```

But how do I make Guice call `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`MessageDigest` is a very special class. All its instances are one-use only. Therefore it must be injected very carefully.

First, you'll have to tell Guice to create multiple instances of the class. This is done as below in your `Module` class.

```
@Provides
MessageDigest provideMD5() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  return MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
}
```

Then, once you have your provider that can create instances everytime, it's injected, you might not actually want only one instance per injected instance. So you will probably have to do the following:

```
@Inject
Provider<MessageDigest> md5Provider;

...

// Later in the class
MessageDigest md5 = md5Provider.get();
```

Comment: This worked. But still need to try a few more similar classes. To use the ```@Provides``` annotation, here's an example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guice/guice_provides_annotation.htm

Comment: Using a Guice Provider for this as an anti-pattern. Provider has its own Guice semantics, so it requires the user to know how this particular binding must be injected.  That's unnecessary if you use something like `Supplier` that has neutral semantics, making mistakes is impossible.

Comment: @Gene `Provider` comes from `javax.inject.*` or from `jakarta.inject.*`, since Guice recommends using those above theirs... And those are the Java standard. Also, `Provider` can and should throw `Exception`, which `Supplier` shouldn't since it's not documented that it can.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

I did not know `MessageDigest` is a single use class. You showed an injection of that class, which by definition cannot provide multiple instances. So the question is flawed.

You must fix the problem by binding a factory function that creates an MD rather than the MD itself.  E.g. a Supplier:

```java
final MessageDigestModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Provide
  Supplier<MessageDigest> provideMd5Digest() {
    return () -> MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  }
}
```

Then when creating the injector, install `new MessageDigestModule()`.
You will use `@Inject Supplier<MessageDigest> md5DigestSupplier;`. At the places where  you need one, you'll say `md5DigestSupplier.get()`.

If you'll need more than one kind of `MessageDigest`, then you should declare annotations and use them to separate the bindings.

```
@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface Md5 {}
@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface Sha256 {}
```

and then

```
final MessageDigestModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Provide
  @Md5
  Supplier<MessageDigest> provideMd5Digest() {
    return () -> MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  }
  @Provide
  @Sha256
  Supplier<MessageDigest> provideMd5Digest() {
    return () -> MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
  }
}
```

And then finally:

```
@Inject
@Sha256
Supplier<MessageDigest> sha128DigestSupplier;
```

Comment: Doesn't work because MessageDigest is just a single-use class. If you have two injected instances they'll both share the same single-use instance and that'll be very messy!

Comment: But this was very helpful. I followed this for other classes.

Comment: Okay.  The question misled me by showing the injection of a single MessageDigest.  I've updated it.  @OlivierGrégoire